# Why can't I install Windows 7 in Gnome Boxes?

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machine, virtualization, gnome, iso-image

I run Fedora 18 Gnome. I have a legal copy of Windows 7 in .iso format. I am attempting to install it in Gnome Boxes.

When I try to install it, I get a message that says "Connection to windows7.iso failed."

I thought maybe it was just that particular .iso file. So, I downloaded Ubuntu and tried that... same thing happened.

What am I missing or what can I do?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: How exactly are you trying to install it?

Comment: I am attempting to install it by selecting the iso from inside Boxes and clicking "create."

Answer (score 0):

The error you describe only appears if you enter a URL. Try downloading the ISO locally and choosing it with the file browser in GNOME Boxes rather than typing in an URL.

Answer (score -1):

I believe that may be due to a Selinux error.  Check your Selinux config and logs.  You might want to try to disable Selinux while testing.

```
sudo setenforce 0
```